# CURL response for python flask is different from LOCAL and Container

Tags: json, python-3.x, flask, curl, containers

I have the below `python` (version 3.9) code with `flask`:

```
def get_location_by_ip(ip):
    url = f'{GEO_IP_SERVICE}/{ip}'

    response = requests.get(url)

    response.raise_for_status()

    return response.json()


@app.route('/v1/api/checkCurrentWeather')
def check_current_weather():
    try:
        location = get_location_by_ip(IP)
        city = location['city']
        country_code = location['countryCode']
    except Exception as ex:
        return {'message': 'FAILURE', 'ex': ex}, 500

    return {"city": city, "country": country_code}, 200
```

when I'm testing it locally using `postman`, it works well, and I'm getting the correct response, but when I'm testing it on `container` (on top of `aws ubuntu` instance with `docker`), I start to get this exception:

`TypeError: Object of type HTTPError is not JSON serializable`

I don't understand why the behavior is different. any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the answer in the python chat room :)
When doing:

```
except Exception as ex:
    return {'message': 'FAILURE', 'ex': str(ex)}, 500
```

`str(ex)` returns the real error:

```
{
  "ex": "401 Client Error: Unauthorized for url: http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=Peta%E1%BA%96%20Tiqwa&appid=None",
  "message": "FAILURE"
}
```

`ex` is giving the exception object as `JSON` does not parse Exception object.

Indeed, I forget to pass in my `docker run` command my env variable. After I did it, the response was as expected.

Tnx to @12944qwerty for his suggestion.